# Render dropdown selected value in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Division">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="Division" runat="server">
          <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Select"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="Computer" Value="Computer"></asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem Text="Electronics" Value="Electronics"></asp:ListItem>
      </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In i am not able to diplay the selected values in the dropdown which is already in the database.

Comment: I think we're going to need a little more detail. What exactly are you trying to do? Are you loading the values in the dropdown from the database, or are they hardcoded (as in your sample)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that you want to have the Division value for the row to be selected in the dropdown, you need to bind the SelectedValue property of the DropDownList to the field in your data source that contains the Division value. It would look something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Division" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Division") %>' >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Selected="True"** as in:

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="Select" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
```